# Can new @Immutable entity be inserted

Tags: hibernate, immutability

I have an entity I want to be insert only. All of the documentation I've found says that an entity annotated with [`@Immutable`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/Immutable.html) cannot be updated, small "u" updated. What I need to know is whether a new immutable instance can be inserted? The entity is a log entry, so I just need the insert. No updates nor deletes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `@Immutable` entities can be inserted.

Note however that `@Immutable` on a Collection means that no additions or deletions to/from the Collection can happen.